# Uninstalling react app from scratch (Linux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linux, npm, create-react-app

I am in the process of creating a React app (using Linux-Ubuntu, npm 3.5.2, node v8.10.0, with npx). I used the following-

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

But to start the app:

```
npx start
```

I got a bit of errors (shown below)

```
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
  "eslint": "^6.6.0"
Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:
  /home/dirsomename/Projects/node_modules/eslint (version: 5.16.0) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:
  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
```

Well, it did not fix the problem even after following the steps above.

So, my goal now is to retrace my steps and to uninstall the complete React app from scratch.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Can't you just cd into my-app and run the command ```npm run start```?

Comment: no, that did not work